# Scrapy "The 'Twisted>=13.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by Scrapy"

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, ubuntu-12.04

I'm installing scrapy on Ubuntu 12.04, python 3.5.2 inside a virtualenv. I've had so much trouble installing scrapy but I've finally got all the requirements installed. I had to manually install twisted to get the installation to complete, but I have Twisted 17.0 installed. However, when I try to run the tutorial I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Twisted>=13.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by Scrapy
```

Twisted 17.0 is installed and seems to be working. When I import scrapy and twisted in python I get no errors (it finds the module), but as a command, scrapy doesn't work.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov  2 2016, 11:15:44) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scrapy
>>> import twisted
```

Comment: Does `which scrapy` point to the `bin/scrapy` in your virtualenv?

Comment: Alternatively to the `bin/scrapy` that `pip install scrapy` should have installed, you can try `python -m scrapy.cmdline` as an alias to `scrapy`, e.g `python -m scrapy.cmdline version -v`

Comment: If possible, consider upgrading from `Ubuntu 12.04` - beginning last month, April 2017, it no longer receives security updates. [Ubuntu Release End-Of-Life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)

Comment: Thanks @chucksmash It is about time that I upgrade Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You will need the build dependencies installed for all of the extension modules involved.  That's going to include at least gcc, libffi-dev, and libssl-dev (but possibly more):

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

With the build dependencies installed, you should install **all** of the *Python* software into the virtualenv.

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 scrapy-environment
. scrapy-environment/bin/activate
pip install scrapy
scrapy ...
```

If you encounter some error with this, you should update your question to include details of that error.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I ended up installing miniconda and installing scrapy through conda forge which worked perfectly. If I need to go back and install without conda, I'll have to try this method